# Interface Segregation in Qt

Tags: qt, interface, solid-principles, interface-segregation-principle

I always try to apply the [S.O.L.I.D](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2009/07/15/the-solid-principles-explained-with-motivational-posters/) principles and I really like the Qt toolkit but I find myself stuggeling all the time with the [single inheritance rule](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first).

> If you are using multiple inheritance,
>   moc assumes that the first inherited
>   class is a subclass of QObject.
>   **Also, be sure that only the first inherited class is a QObject.**

How do you combine the single inheritance from a QObject rule and the *Interface Segregation Principle*.
I want to define the interfaces with signals and slots, but I'm not allowed to do this.

How do you get around this shortcomming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that signals and slots are nothing more than functions that have special behaviors. Thus, you *can* use them to create interfaces.

For a full description of the process and a complete workaround for complex cases, see [Qt Quarterly #15](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq15-academic.html#multipleinheritance).

Comment: In the linked article a qobject_cast to the interface is performed, but the interface is not a QObject... should that be a dynamic_cast instead?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can easily get around that with Qt's signal/slot mechanisms.  You could try looking at either boost::signals or the sigc library, which are both more flexible in where you can place signals and slots.  Be aware of possible namespace collisions with either library and Qt's `signals` and `slots` macros.